# STM32 - How to understand if GPIO is high current or not?

Tags: stm32, gpio, output

I'm working with the [STM32F303](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f303cb.pdf) Microcontroller. The datasheet says that almost all pins are high-current, with the exception of analog inputs.

[image]

I want to select multiple outputs to drive the indication LEDs (up to 5 mA per LED).
My options: PA0..PA7, P0..PB2.
They all have an alternative analog input function.

Is this a sign that they can't put out much current as an output?

Comment: It reads in the datasheet electrical specifications table.

Comment: I know. Before asking a question, I spent time looking for this answer. And I couldn't find it in the datasheet. I will be glad if you help me find this information. Datasheet specified.

Comment: Did you read section 6.3.14 "I/O port characteristics" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP's data sheet answers all.
We don't know how many LEDs will be driven. If many LEDs are ON at the same time, you must meet a few requirements:

- Maximum total I/O current limit of 80mA
- Chip operating temperature limit, which is package-dependent.
- Chip power dissipation limit, which is package-dependent.

An example from OP's linked data sheet for STM32F303 on page 140 (out of 149):

> Example 1: High-performance application 
> Assuming the following
> application conditions: Maximum ambient temperature T Amax = 82 °C
> (measured according to JESD51-2), IDDmax = 50 mA, V DD = 3.5 V,
> maximum 3 I/Os used at the same time in output at low level with I OL
> = 8 mA, VOL = 0.4 V and maximum 2 I/Os used at the same time in output at low level with I OL = 20 mA, VOL = 1.3 V

For the output pins that supply 8mA, the equivalent internal resistance of the N-channel MOSFET inside the STM32F303 is:
 0.4V/8mA= 50 ohms, which causes an additional 3.2mW of power that the chip must dissipate.

For the output pins that supply 20mA, the equivalent internal resistance of the N-channel MOSFET inside the STM32303 is:
1.3/.02 = 65 ohms, which causes an additional 26mW power that the chip must dissipate.

Be aware that ST sets a limit for chip operating temperature, and a separate limit for how much net current flows out of all GPIO pins (80 mA total) and *another limit* for total DC chip current of 160mA. LED current would contribute toward that 80mA limit.
Since this chip has multiple DC supply pins (and multiple GND pins), ST sets a limit for how much current *each* of these **supply pins** should pass: 100mA. LED current would contribute toward this limit too, along with current of the core processor.
Its all in that data sheet.

Any **single GPIO pin** is rated up to 20mA, and its max limit is 25mA. If you were driving 4 LEDs at the 20mA max, you'd be at the 80mA limit for total I/O output current. Any current on other output pins would put you over the limit. The chip would run warmer (perhaps too warm) as well.

A tip: CMOS GPIO outputs often do better when they sink current toward the GND (Vss) pin, and do a tad worse when sourcing current from Vdd pin. So arrange your LEDs with anode toward Vdd, and turn them on by driving GPIO pin **LOW**. (Add a series resistor, of course).

Comment: A single GPIO has an **Absolute maximum** of 25mA. It is rated for up to 20mA sink or source.

Comment: @Justme yes, text modified to distinguish this 5mA difference.

Comment: glen_geek, Thank you for the answer! I use only two LEDs, 10mA in total.

Answer (score 4):

In the datasheet [STM32F303cb](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f303cb.pdf) review tables 12 and 13.  These tables list the alternate pin functions of each pin.

(Note that you also need to know the exact chip package type, obviously not all ports are available on the smaller chip packages.)

For example in table 13 the pins listed with an I/O structure of "TTa" are the ADC input pins, which are analog inputs - which are not high current capable.

As in the comments - see section 6.3.14 for more specific I/O port characteristics.

You also need to adhere to the maximum limits as listed in the answer from glen_geek.

Comment: Nedd, Thank you for the answer!